# Getting values from JSON multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON array that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 258,
    "rawId": null,
    "displayName": null,
    "name": {
        "givenName": "my ame",
        "honorificSuffix": "",
        "formatted": "my ame",
        "middleName": "",
        "familyName": "",
        "honorificPrefix": ""
    },
    "nickname": "",
    "phoneNumbers": [{
        "value": "23423442342424",
        "pref": false,
        "id": 0,
        "type": "mobile"
    }],
    "emails": null,
    "addresses": null,
    "ims": null,
    "organizations": [{
        "pref": "false",
        "title": "",
        "name": "",
        "department": "",
        "type": null
    }],
    "birthday": null,
    "note": "",
    "photos": null,
    "categories": null,
    "urls": null
}
```

I need to get the phoneNumbers >> value from this JSON.

SO I TRIED SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

`var d = JSON.parse(test);
alert(test[0].phoneNumbers.value);`

The variable test is the JSON shown above.

and I also tried:

`alert(d[0].phoneNumbers.value);`

and

`alert(test.phoneNumbers.value);`

But none of the above work.

Is there something that I am missing in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `d.phoneNumbers[0].value`

Comment: phoneNumbers is an array so you should iterate that to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you showed us is a JSON string (giving a JS object after parsing), not an array.

So `d[0].phoneNumbers` will not work and `d.phoneNumbers` will work and will give you an array.

And because it will give you an array, `d.phoneNumbers.value` will not work, and `d.phoneNumbers[0].value` will.

Comment: `test` is the original string, the OP has given the name `d` to the object formed by parsing it